# How to call a method with a body in an Interface

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an interface defined as:

```
interface IProperty<T>
{
    public T Value { get;  set; }

    public T GetTheValue()
    {
        return (T)(Value);
    }
}
```

An implementation as:

```
class Animal : IProperty<string>
{
    public string Value { get;  set; }
}
```

Used as:

```
var camel = new Animal { Value = "Camel" };
```

How can instances of the `Animal` class access the `GetTheValue()` method in the `IProperty<T>` interface? (Nothing is showing up in IntelliSense)

And if it cannot, what is the purpose of methods with a body in the Interface?

Comment: It will work if you declare your variable like this `IProperty<string> camel = new Animal { Value = "Camel" };`

Comment: why not place the 'answer' in a place where it can be accepted as an Answer?